# Multi-select text input on screen after closing modal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-select

I have a modal and after I close the modal I want to show on the screen the options that were selected on the modal.

My code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-xdpj7?file=/src/CreatableInputOnly.tsx

On this fragment below I am calling the part that handles the text on the modal on `CreatableInputOnly`. The part that handles the dropdown is on the `ReactSelect` call:

```
<Fragment>
      <Button onClick={handleClickOpen}>ModalButton</Button>
      <div>Selected options on the modal were: </div>
      <Dialog
        maxWidth={"sm"}
        fullWidth={true}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        classes={{
          paperFullWidth: classes.paperFullWidth
        }}
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">Dialog</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent
          classes={{
            root: classes.dialogContentRoot
          }}
        >
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <FormControl style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                <ReactSelect isMulti={true} options={country} />
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <CreatableInputOnly />
          </Grid>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} variant="contained">
            Close
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a state variable in the `ModalTest.tsx` and pass the setter function to the select component `reactMaterialSelect.tsx`.

```
const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = React.useState([]);
```

Then, you can update the code, which will display the selected options. Its just a simple map function printing a `label` of each index item.

```
<div>
    Selected options on the modal were:{" "}
    {selectedValues?.length
      ? selectedValues.map((item, idx) =>
          idx !== 0 ? `, ${item.label}` : item.label
        )
      : ""}
</div>
```

Update the component part to send the additional prop of state setter value.

```
<ReactSelect
   handleSelectValues={setSelectedValues}
   isMulti={true}
   options={country}
 />
```

In `reactMaterialSelect.tsx`, the change function are updated to change the state in the parent variable.

```
function handleChangeSingle(value) {
  setSingle(value);
  handleSelectValues([value]);
}

function handleChangeMulti(value) {
  setMulti(value);
  handleSelectValues(value);
}
```

To manage the `createdInputs`, a new state variable is added.

```
const [createAbleInputs, setCreateAbleInputs] = React.useState([]);
```

A variable to combine the results of both states.

```
const combinedArray =
createAbleInputs === null
  ? [...selectedValues]
  : [...selectedValues, ...createAbleInputs];
```

Then the compoent `createableInputsOnly` is updated to change the state in the modal based on the changes in the component.

[Updated sandbox link.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-forked-gqo5e?file=/src/reactMaterialSelect.js:6992-7182)

Comment: Hi Junaid! Thank you for your answer :) I have a question, for me on your codesandbox I cannot see what was written on the textbox, I just can see what was selected on the dropbox. It should be like this?

Comment: I'm updating the codesandbox.

Comment: I've updated the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-forked-gqo5e?file=/src/ModalTest.tsx). Please review @catarina-nogueira

Comment: That's amazing Junaid! I've seen what you have done, is very smart! Thank you :)

Comment: ps: I am struggling with another part of code that is on the same subject of this question, if you want to have a look: :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69360054/just-update-the-state-of-one-element-on-the-list-react-typescript

Comment: Hi again :) 
I was exploring more the code and I realized that if I choose some values on the modal and close it when I open again the values are not shown inside the modal as the actual selection. I was wondering (and trying) how can I do this. Any ideas? :)

Comment: You can pass the state from the modal component to the `select` and `createAbleInput`  component. In those components, you can initialize the state coming from the props .